# What is other alternative to use spring bean without wiring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, spring-mvc

I am using this in my UserDAO and hibernate

```
@Resource(name="sessionFactory");
public SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

For some reason i am not able to link spring beans in my userDAO from 2 different classes.

What is the other alternative of above code i mean something like

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Sessionfactory()
```

is that ok

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>testing</display-name>


  <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml

        </param-value>
    </context-param>




  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/krams/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">


    <import resource="hibernate-context.xml" />


    <mvc:annotation-driven /> 

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource" p:basename="messages" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.vaannila" />

    <bean id="userService" class="com.vaannila.service.UserServiceImpl" />

    <bean id="userValidator" class="com.vaannila.validator.UserValidator" />
     <bean id="registrationDAO" class="com.vaannila.dao.RegistrationDAO" />
     <bean id="userDAO" class="com.vaannila.dao.UserDAO" />





   <bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
      <property name="velocityProperties">
         <value>
          resource.loader=class
          class.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
         </value>
      </property>
   </bean>



</beans>
```

hibernate-context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            ">

    <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring.properties" />

    <!-- Enable annotation style of managing transactions -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />   

    <!-- Declare the Hibernate SessionFactory for retrieving Hibernate sessions -->
    <!-- See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html -->                           
    <!-- See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/index.html?org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html -->
    <!-- See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/index.html?org/hibernate/Session.html -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
                 p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
                 p:configLocation="${hibernate.config}"
                 p:packagesToScan="com.vaannila"/>

    <!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities-->   
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
                destroy-method="close"
                p:driverClass="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"
                p:jdbcUrl="${app.jdbc.url}"
                p:user="${app.jdbc.username}"
                p:password="${app.jdbc.password}"
                p:acquireIncrement="5"
                p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
                p:maxPoolSize="100"
                p:maxStatements="50"
                p:minPoolSize="10" />

    <!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" 
                p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

</beans>
```

Comment: *For some reason i am not able to link spring beans in my userDAO from 2 different classes* what does this sentence mean?

Comment: what's in hibernate-context ?

Comment: i have included the hibernate file

Comment: looks fine. are you sure you are not doing `new UserDao()` somewhere?

Comment: no i haven't , i have used this example http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-integration_18.html , if u see CustomUserDetails.java class there he is using new useDAO , i want to convert that to bean

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not OK. The fresh `SessionFactory` won't be initialized properly (it lacks all the required configurations that you have set in `applicationContext.xml`).

So make sure you have a bean named `sessionFactory` and `<context:component-scan .. />`

Also note that beans defined in `dispatcher-servlet.xml` are not visible for beans defined in `applicationContext.xml`

Comment: i don't have any applicationContext.xml file . do i need it . i am using spring3  and without it , my app is running

Comment: @Pasha - it seems it's not exactly 'running'. please share your web.xml and any spring configuration file you have.

Answer (score 0):

No that is not ok. 
You can use autowire feature of spring.

In case you don't like to use annotation for linking, consider using application-context.xml for linking(injecting) your sessionFactory.

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing enough context. I don't even understand what your problem is, nor what's not working. Please show some configuration and some output.

But:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Sessionfactory()
```

If you are using code like this, there's no point of using an IOC container like Spring in the first place, because you are missing out on the key concept, dependency injection.